# Codeigniter rename downloaded file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say the user upload a zip file called codeigniter.zip. And my application saved it with name 1.zip that is the file's id in database table. Also it saved file's original name to the table. If the user download this file he download it by name 1.zip. How can i give this file to the user with name codeigniter.zip? Thank you.

Comment: you set the filename in the header: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileNameFromDatabase");`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$actual_filename = '1.zip'; // I assume this will come from some model's method
$desired_filename = 'codeigniter.zip' // same is assumed here
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $desired_filename);

echo file_get_contents('/path/to/' . $actual_filename);
```

`Content-Disposition: attachment` should make the browser prompt the user to download the file, and  `filename=` tells the browser what to call the file [by default].